# Software asking for obsolete version of Java (6) on macOS 10.15

Tags: mac, java, macos-catalina

I have a friend that is trying to run the following software (cmap) https://cmap.ihmc.us/cmaptools/cmaptools-download/
She gets prompted to install Java SE 6 to run the software. She last used it in December 2019 and it worked fine. I suspect it is the OS. Here is a note by Oracle on macOS 10.15.

[image: Here is a note by Oracle on macOS 10.15]

She updates her OS automatically, and she is on macOS Catalina 10.15.2.
She later installed Java SE 8, and this is the message output when she tries to install Java SE 6.

[image: this is the message output when she tries to install Java SE 6]

Basically it says she can't install it as a more recent version of Java is already installed on her OS, however the problem persists. I thought about uninstalling the recent Java version and keeping the old one to run Cmap, however, as this Java version is obsolete, I don't want to damage other software on her computer. What should I advise her to do?

As she doesn't code at all, she doesn't need a JDK, only a JRE right?

I just looked here's what it says on the installation:

System Requirements:
CmapTools v6 and above run under Java 7 (Java is included as part of the installation), and therefore a requirement is the capability to run Java 7.
Intel-based Mac running Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion) or later

So basically she probably just installed the wrong version of cmap which didn't come with the right Java binary? Then would the solution be to uninstall cmap and reinstall the right version?

Comment: To run a Java-based program, she needs Java JRE, that's right. This said, it's the software editor's fault, more than Apple's, in this case. The editor should have made the necessary adjustments so that newer versions of Java are supporter by their app. You can indeed uninstall Java 8, and install Java 6 manually, but a lot of security fixes would go out the window in that case. Are you sure the software editor doesn't propose a more recent version that's compatible with Java 8? Oftentimes, they pack Java with their own binaries, especially on macOS.

Comment: Java is backward compatible.  This means if your friend has Java 8 installed it can run Java 6 software.  The problem appears to be a system path issue, but the screenshots are not in English, so I can't confirm that fact.

Comment: if the cause was the system path, i would expect the software to have never worked as she probably didnt touch her $path